# Using dynamic SQL to specify a column name by adding a variable to simple sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

sql 2005/ sql 2008

```
Declare @temp nvarchar(1000)

set @temp = 'ABC'


select col1,col2 from tableA
```

Along with select query, how to add a variable to the select query ?

```
expected output :-

select col1,col2,@temp as [col3] from tableA
```

Where @temp specifies the name of a column in tableA.

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? Are you getting errors? What are they?

Comment: Yeah, this is a simple syntax error. There is no column name @temp i the table : tableA. So it will throw error

Comment: Try select col1,col2,'ABC' as [col3] from tableA

Comment: Some languages support this construct 'natively' For example in Foxpro you could prefix the variable with an "&" which would tell the compiler to concat the value into the query. A process known as macro Substitution. It's very powerful but it doesn't allow for a lot of important steps of a modern rdbms and it allow SQL injection.

Comment: i have to agree with Stephanie Page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to specify the column name dynamically, you could take a look at executing dynamic sql.  However, you should make sure to read about the dangers of this approach first:

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

From that page, there is a sample that shows dynamically specifying the table name -- you could change it so it dynamically specifies the column name instead:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE general_select @tblname nvarchar(128),
                                @key     varchar(10),
                                @debug   bit = 0 AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT col1, col2, col3
            FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tblname) + '
            WHERE keycol = @key'
IF @debug = 1 PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@key varchar(10)', @key = @key
```

So for example if you had a table 'MyTable' with columns named 'x', 'y', and 'z', it might look like:

```
DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
set @columnName = 'z'

SET @sql = 'SELECT x, y, ' + @columnName + ' from MyTable'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnName varchar(128)', @columnName = @columnName
```

Comment: select * from [udf_ComplianceMembers] (@PatId) :- Thats my actual query, to which i need to add a Dynamic Column / Variable : @Compliance. I don't know how to add a dynamic column to it

Comment: This is how to do it, but before you do this look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Why are you concatenating + @columnName + *and* passing it to sp_executesql as a parameter?

Comment: @stepahniepage, i read that article. Our purpose of this query is for internal / generating reports and not for commercial !! so, i guess we dont have to worry about sql injection

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select col1,col2 from tableA WHERE col1 = @temp
```

Or this:

```
select col1,col2,@temp as col3 from tableA WHERE col1 = @temp
```

Or this:

```
select col1,col2,@temp as col3 from tableA
```

Or if @temp is a column name, then maybe you're looking for a dynamic query?

```
 SET @temp = 'select col1,col2, ' + @temp + ' as col3 from tableA'
 EXEC sp_executesql @temp
```

...

Comment: yes i am looking for Dynamic SQL Query by adding a dynamic column name !!

Comment: select * from [udf_ComplianceMembers] (@PatId)   :- Thats my actual query, to which i need to add a Dynamic Column / Variable : @Compliance. I don't know how to add a dynamic column to it

Comment: You need to add @Compliance to your UDF (TVF)?  You can always pass it in...but you'll need to update the UDF to use it.  What is the code for your UDF?

Comment: can you please help me in writing the syntax, i dont know how to pass or exactly what are you trying to say

Comment: select * from [udf_ComplianceMembers] (@PatId, @Compliance)

Comment: udf_ComplianceMembers takes only one Input parameter. We cannot pass @Compliance to it