# Can I pass variable to select statement as column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Select dynamic column name based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637983/sql-select-dynamic-column-name-based-on-variable)

I have the following simple `select` statement:

```
 DECLARE @value varchar(10) 
 SET @value = 'intStep' 

 SELECT @value FROM dbo.tblBatchDetail
```

I have tried

```
 SELECT CAST(@value AS varchar(10)) FROM dbo.tblBatchDetail
```

and all I get a list of `intstep`

**QUESTION**: can I pass variable as column name to this statement? Or what is the best way of doing this

I'm using SQL Server 2008 (9.0 RTM)

This will be a stored procedure

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a dup of this question [Using dynamic SQL to specify a column name by adding a variable to simple sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123659/using-dynamic-sql-to-specify-a-column-name-by-adding-a-variable-to-simple-sql-qu)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't use variable names to bind columns or other system objects, you need dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @value varchar(10)  
SET @value = 'intStep'  
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000); 

SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ' + @value + ' FROM dbo.tblBatchDetail'
Exec (@sqlText)
```

Comment: i get this error Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 6
Could not find stored procedure 'SELECT intStep FROM dbo.tblBatchDetail'.

Comment: Sorry forgot parenthesys around @sqlText, answer updated