# Select a column using a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was wondering if there is a way to select a column by using a SQL variable. Eg. Table is - 
ID, Name, Address

```
DECLARE @Column varchar(25)
SET @Column = 'Name' -- This can be another column also
SELECT @Column
FROM MyTable
```

This shows me 'Name' as many times as there are rows in my table. 
Is it even possible to do what I want ?

thanks.

Comment: It is exactly that in my opinion, have you tried it?

Comment: While dynamic SQL will work, it can get very complicated very fast. It also fails to be reusable as it [cannot (easily) be combined with queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492411/sql-server-select-from-stored-procedure). (That is to say, I would advise against designs that are *based* around this operation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql is currently interpreting your variable as a string.

[From a previous answer on stack overflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896225/2171102)

```
DECLARE @Column varchar(25)
SET @Column = 'Name' -- This can be another column also
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ' + @Column + ' FROM MyTable'
EXEC (@sqlText)
```

Answer (score 3):

Can do this with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Column varchar(25)
       ,@sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Column = 'Name' -- This can be another column also
SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@Column+'
            FROM MyTable
            '
EXEC (@sql)
```

You can test your dynamic sql queries by changing `EXEC` to `PRINT` to make sure each of the resulting queries is what you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic SQL for that:

```
DECLARE @Column nvarchar(25)
SET @Column = 'Name' -- This can be another column also
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT ' + @Column + N' FROM MyTable'

exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare the sqltext as well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).