# How to retrieve a column value using a variable

Tags: sql

I have a single SQL table with columns Mary, Joe, Pat and Mick
I have rows of values for each persons weekly expenses

I want a single sproc to query a persons weekly expense value

i.e. a sproc that takes two variables @PersonsName and @WeekNumber and returns a single value

It wont work for me.  It will work if I specify the persons name in the query but not if I pass the persons name to the query.

I'm pulling my hair out - is this something to do with Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Entirely doable with a sproc. Post what you have tried so we can help troubleshoot it for you.

Comment: Please change your table design. That is not how you do it. Don't use data as column names. Add some example data and we might help you find a better design.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are really digging into performance, scalability etc. as your scenario seems like a small personal tool. But still... as juergen suggested, you better design the schema in a different way. your current design won't scale easily if you want to add one more person to your database. 
Instead, you can have something like

- a persons table(person name, person Id)
- an expenses table (week number, person id, expense)

This scales well. and with indexing on person id your queries can be faster

Suggestions apart, 
[Can I pass variable to select statement as column name in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896147/can-i-pass-variable-to-select-statement-as-column-name-in-sql-server) seems to provide answer for your question