# Using the output of subquery as the fields of main query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there any way that I can use the output of subquery as the fields of the next query?

```
SELECT TEAM_ID, ID1, ID2, ID3 FROM XYZ;
```

to

```
SELECT TEAM_ID, (SELECT IDs FROM ABC WHERE GROUP_ID="1") FROM XYZ;
```

Schema for XYZ

```
TEAM_ID, ID1, ID2, ID3
   50, B001, A003, S001 
   60, B002, A111, M001
```

Schema for ABC

```
Group_ID, IDs
1, ID1,ID2,ID3
2, ID1,ID3
3, ID2
```

Now, I want: 
    TEAM_ID, ID1, ID2, ID3
    50, B001, A003, S001

Based on Group_ID=1

Comment: which sql engine and version?

Comment: As I understand you mean to use the value of IDs column of ABC schema as column names inorder to construct a query for schema XYZ ?

Comment: This colud helps you https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery

Comment: SQL Standard - In BigQuery

Comment: Abhay, that's correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896147/can-i-pass-variable-to-select-statement-as-column-name-in-sql-server

Comment: @AmirCS - did you really mean `GROUP_ID="1"` - using static `"1"` here sounds as typo - please confirm

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant just provided more info about the example. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AmirCS - nope. not really :o( are you saying that by group_id you want to control the columns to be in result?? that would be quite a different ask from what you originally posted (which didn't make much sense)

Comment: Yes, "the output of subquery as the `fields` of main query". Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`:

```
SELECT X.TEAM_ID, A.*
FROM X CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT IDs FROM ABC WHERE ABC.GROUP_ID = '1') a
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! This returns back the field names, but it would not be able to query these fields and the content of the columns in BigQuery. I added an example to the question. Do you think this is something even possible? Thanks so much and sorry for the confusion!