# Removing Rows from one Table based off another table that has key/value pair

Tags: plsql

```
Table1 { name = 'bob' job='trucker' gender='male' car='blue' } Table1 { name = 'dave' job='Driver' gender='male' car='red' } Table1 { name = 'jane' job='loader' gender='female' car='purple' }

table2 ( removeID="name" removeKey="jane"} table2 ( removeID="car" removeKey="red"}
```

I need to know what SQL I could use that would give the following result:

```
Table1 { name = 'bob' job='trucker' gender='male' car='blue' }
```

I'm starting to think this is not possible and that I have to compare columns to columns

Comment: Looks like you need some [dynamic sql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7123659/27439)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DELETE_FROM_TABLE1
  strSql  VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2)
  LOOP
    strSql := 'DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE ' ||
                aRow.REMOVEID || '= ''' ||
                aRow.REMOVEKEY || '''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strSql;
  END LOOP;
END DELETE_FROM_TABLE1;
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first!

Share and enjoy.