# Select @variable from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me I am trying to do this:

```
 DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(500) = ' declare @col as nvarchar(50) = ''RoleID''
  select @col from tblRole '
  EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY
```

Here `RoleID` is a column name in `tblRole` but I am getting result like this:

```
RoleID 
RoleID 
RoleID 
RoleID 
RoleID 
RoleID 
RoleID
```

How to read proper data from sql table in this way?

Comment: You cannot "parametrize" table or column names. If you want to do this, you have to use **dynamic SQL** with all its benefits (and drawbacks)

Comment: why you want to do so?

Comment: @marc_s I am doing this in store procedure with EXEC sp_executesql. But I am stuck at this point

Comment: @AngularDev I am working on a Pivot report. In this report before returning result to project, I have to modify its values on some conditions. That is why I need to do in this way.

Comment: Please help me I am still not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the RoleID column then your select should be...

SELECT RoleID FROM tblRole

If you want to select a value = 'RoleID' then...

SELECT * FROM tblRole where RoleID = @col

IF on the other hand you want to select a column by dynamically passing it as a variable then click on the link below.

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123659/using-dynamic-sql-to-specify-a-column-name-by-adding-a-variable-to-simple-sql-qu)

Comment: Yes @Andrew N I need to select column by passing it dynamically.
this link looks relevant. I am working on it

Comment: Please help me I am still not able to do it.